# How to check on variables updates from a singleton in ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a singleton class that manages datas for my application so I can use them in different `ViewControllers`.

The thing is that I want to watch for updates of this datas in my `ViewController`and I don't know how to do it. I managed to do a version where I call `viewDidLoad()` while my data isn't the way I want it but I think this is the ugliest way to do this.

My Singleton is simple as that :

```
class DataProvider {
    static let sharedInstance = DataProvider()
    let apiClient = APIClient()
    var token: String? = ""
    
    private init() {
        apiClient.getToken { data in
            self.token = data.token
        }
    }

    
}
```

So it fetch a token on application start and I can use this token to make api calls in different `ViewControllers`

An example of that is my entry view where I need to make an API call on `viewDidLoad()`:

```
class IndexViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: IndexViewControllerDelegate?
    let apiClient = APIClient()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if DataProvider.sharedInstance.token != "" {
            loadSomething()
        } else {
            viewDidLoad()
        }
    }

    func loadSomething() {
        apiClient.getSomething() { something in
            self.somethingHere = something.somethingHere
        }
    }



...
```

As you can see I call `viewDidLoad()` when my token isn't corresponding to what I need. This is not a proper way to do it and I'm wondering how I can watch for updates from my singleton.

Comment: I would go for Combine framework and have an observable property that can keep on sending values and i can listen to those values in my viewController. Just an overview.

Comment: Won't use combine as I need to be compatible with previous iOS versions

Comment: If you don't want to use Combine then a good old `NotificationCenter` approach would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is closure callback:-

```
    static let sharedInstance = DataProvider()
    let apiClient = APIClient()
    // put didSet in token here
    var token: String? = "" {
        didSet {
            tokenUpdateCallback?(token)
        }
    }
    var tokenUpdateCallback : ((String?) -> Void)?
    
    private init() {
        apiClient.getToken { data in
            self.token = data.token
        }
    }
    
    
}

class IndexViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: IndexViewControllerDelegate?
    let apiClient = APIClient()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add this code below here
        
        DataProvider.sharedInstance.tokenUpdateCallback = { token in
            if let token = token {
                print(token)
            }
            // You'll get callback of your updated token
        }
        
        if DataProvider.sharedInstance.token != "" {
            loadSomething()
        } else {
            viewDidLoad()
        }
    }
    
    func loadSomething() {
        apiClient.getSomething() { something in
            self.somethingHere = something.somethingHere
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing so.

Solution 1: Use RXSwift

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Solution 2

```html
class IndexViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: IndexViewControllerDelegate?
    let apiClient = APIClient()
    
    // make sure you share the singleton here
    dataProvider: DataProvider
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // make sure DataProvider instance is not empty and pass it as prop 
        if dataProvider.token != "" {
            loadSomething()
        } else {
            viewDidLoad()
        }
    }

    func loadSomething() {
        apiClient.getSomething() { something in
            self.somethingHere = something.somethingHere
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, you are accessing Singelton here not passing it as decency, it might happen that on creation time the singleton is not instantiated 
RXSwift is the best I would say